# Changing % formatting to f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

```
colors = ['black', 'white']
sizes = ['S', 'M', 'L']
for tshirt in ('%s %s' % (c, s) for c in colors for s in sizes):
    print(tshirt)

black S
black M
black L
white S
white M
white L
```

So I am trying to remove those %s %s and instead have a f string formatting. Can someone be kind enough to show how this is done. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> colors = ['black', 'white']
>>> sizes = ['S', 'M', 'L']
>>> for c in colors:
...    for s in sizes:
...        print(f'{c} {s}')
```

Another approach is to use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> for c, s in itertools.product(colors, sizes):
...     print(f'{c} {s}')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write the variable names in *curly brackets* (`{...}`):

```
for tshirt in (f'{c} {s}' for c in colors for s in sizes):
    print(tshirt)
```

Although it is a bit strange to use a generator in this case for a `for` loop: you can *unfold* this into (two) nested `for` loops, like in @nosklo's answer (although this of course does not change anything about the usage of the [*literal string interpolation* [PEP-498]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/?).

Comment: I agree that the generator is confusing here and adds complexity for no benefit - in fact it probably uses more memory than the normal loops. I put the normal loops in my answer for that reason

Comment: Still, better to first show how to make just the change to the OP's code that they asked for, and then explain why and how it could be improved, than to imply that rewriting everything is required in order to make the OP's change when it really isn't.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. May I know why you guys find it more complex and memory consuming. Isn't it more compact and easier than the for loop? I am sorry I am still new to this and so am not aware about big-O and time complexities.

Comment: @Damon: well you create a generator, which will consume some extra memory, and you then iterate over the generator, thus there will be some extra overhead with the protocol. The time complexity is the same, but typically there will be a small amount of overhead when working with generators.

Comment: @Damon There's not going to be a big-O difference, but there will be an extra constant term in the space (the generator state isn't huge, but it's not free), and an extra constant factor in the time (it's effectively doing the exact same two loops, plus the cost of going through a `yield` for each element).

Comment: @Damon Comprehensions, and particularly generator expressions, are useful when you want to store or pass around the iterator to iterate later, or feed through a function like `zip` or something out of `itertools` (which will iterate them in C), but they're only useful as the iterable expression in a `for` statement (or the iterable in another comprehension) in somewhat uncommon special cases.